# Rails syntax error, unexpected ')'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber

This is going to be a really dumb question, and I almost hate myself for asking it, but here goes.

When I run my Cucumber test, I'm getting a "syntax error, unexpected ')'" with the following code:

inside my user model:

```
def member?(gallery)
    array = []
    self.groups.each do |group|
        array << group.id
    end
    if array.include?(gallery.group.id)
        true
    end
end
```

And in my view:

```
<ul>
<% @galleries.each do |gallery| %>
    <% if current_user.member?(gallery) %>
    <li>
        <%= link_to gallery.title, gallery %>
    </li>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

EDIT: Here is the important part of the error in full:

```
 ~/Coding/Rails/galleryTest/app/views/galleries/index.html.erb:8: syntax error, unexpected     ')', expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n'
  ... current_user.member? gallery );@output_buffer.safe_concat('
  ...                               ^
  ~/Coding/Rails/galleryTest/app/views/galleries/index.html.erb:13: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'
  ');    end 
            ^
```

EDIT 2: Here is the error when removing the '=':

```
Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id (ActionView::Template::Error)
  ./app/models/user.rb:18:in `member?'
```

I have tried a few different things, and I've got to be missing something really trivial. Another pair of eyes would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Comment: The `if` in the erb file shouldn't be `<%=`; see if that helps.

Comment: I tried that, and there is a new error...

Comment: Can a gallery not have a group? I have no clue what line 18 is.

Comment: Yea, when I check in the rails console, a gallery can have a single group, which is how I have things setup. That's why I'm at a loss... =\

Comment: I'm not asking if it *can*, I'm asking if they all *do* :)

Comment: BTW, `array = self.groups.collect { |g| g.id }`, or `self.groups.map(&:id)`

Comment: Is there really anything specific to Cucumber about this? Does it happen if you browse the site normally?

Comment: I haven't browsed the site normally, setting up the user accounts and linking the galleries, etc., would be cumbersome, hence wanting to run a cucumber test to test the functionality.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I appreciate the revised array lines. I knew there had to be a better way. ;) Also, a gallery doesn't have to have a group; those without groups area considered to be public galleries. How would you suggest I exclude nil-grouped galleries?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<%= if current_user.member?(gallery) %>
```

should be:

```
<% if current_user.member?(gallery) %>
```

Not that there is no `=`, it  means output and your code is trying to output the response of the if block.

Comment: I tried that, and now there is a new error. What are your thoughts on that line? Thank you very much!

Comment: Seems like `gallery.group` is `nil`, hence getting `called id for nil` - which line is line 18 in your `member?` function?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, here is what I have, and how it seems to be working:

In my user model:

```
def member?(gallery)
    array = self.groups.collect { |g| g.id }
    if array.include?(gallery.group_id)
        true
    end
end
```

In my view:

```
<% if user_signed_in?  %>
<ul id="private_galleries">
    <% @galleries.each do |gallery| %>
            <% if current_user.member?(gallery) %>
            <li>
                <%= link_to gallery.title, gallery %>
            </li>
            <% end %>
    <% end %>
</ul>
<% end %>

<ul>
<% @galleries.each do |gallery| %>
    <% if gallery.group_id == nil %>
        <li>
            <%= link_to gallery.title, gallery %>
        </li>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

My tests are running alright now, but they aren't passing, which is strange, as when I set up users with groups and galleries with groups and view them with the site running, they seem to be showing appropriately, which just means my tests are probably effed. That'll be a task for the morning, and probably another question on StackOverflow!